# Rails 3.2 - ambiguous column name: title_es: - What is the right syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am repeatingly having the same error when trying to deal with my search form. Having a look at the internet seems clear that my query needs to be more specific so Rails knows which column to look at, at any single moment.
From the error I understand that the problem comes from the 'title_es' column which belongs to Headers. However, I have tried many different ways and I cannot get the right syntax to make it work. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks

Event Model

```
scope :with_timetable, joins(:header).where(headers: {weekly: true})
```

Event controller

```
def search
    @events_weekly = Event.with_timetable.where((["CAST(title_es as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(title_en as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(title_eu as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] || ["CAST(title_fr as varchar(255)) LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"])).includes(:header)


if @time.wday == 1
      @events = @events_weekly.joins(:timetable).where(timetables: {mon: true})
elsif @time.wday == 2
       .........
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify table name, something like `"CAST(events.title_es as varchar(255))"` or `"CAST(headers.title_es as varchar(255))"` depending on what you need.

I guess you have to specify table name `title_eu` too.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I was trying in singular (event, header). That is the reason it did not work. Thanks for spotting that!